# jquery.signalr CDN fallback

Tags: jquery, signalr, cdn, fallback

I use jQuery from Google CDN and fallback to local copy:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js">\x3C/script>')
</script>
```

But I also want to use CDN for jquery.signalr:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/signalr/jquery.signalr-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

But how I can check if I need fallback for jquery.signalr?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same idea as what you do for jQuery, only instead of checking `window.jQuery` now check for `$.signalR`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also access jquery.signalr using this link:

https://unpkg.com/signalr@2.4.0/jquery.signalR.js

For details please see https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/4270